# Netsuite Saved Search Criteria Formula with 2 fields

Tags: oracle, netsuite

I'm trying to do a saved search filter with a formula (text) criteria based on 2 fields, an item field and custom field.
How can I write the correct formula text in criteria? to create the correct filter to find a specific word in this 2 fields

Eg: I have items called with special nomenclature (SERIAL NUMBER_CODE) and also I created a custom field into journal entry line called (SERIAL NUMBER_CODE_RELATED not an item) now I need to find in the saved search all type of transaction with a specific SERIAL NUMBER_CODE + journal entry that have that SERIAL CODE as well into the line, also add a filter that a user can type the SERIAL CODE and bring transactions + journals.

I used this formula (text) in criteria:
CASE WHEN {custom_field} = 'SERIALCODE' OR {item} = 'SERIALCODE' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
IS = space

Type = all kind of netsuite transaction

in available filter tap I added formula text show in filter region

the result doesn't bring me anything

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

formulatext NVL({custom_field},{item}) is %

Or

formulatext {custom_field}||' '||{item} contains space

Comment: Both formulas, show me all transaction with custom field and item, but when I want to filter with a specific SERIALCODE the result is 0

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of your Criteria and Filter?

Comment: Do you have any other Formulatext Criteria?

Comment: Now is working with the second formula by mistake I added another filter that I did not notice. Thank you so much!!!